# Как сделать иконку к просмотренной ссылке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня такой вопрос, как мне сделать не просмотренную ссылку(1) и просмотренную ссылку(2), как на картинке. Я конечно понимаю, что это скорее всего легко реализуемо, но мне честно нужна помощь. Перепробовал всё. Полазил в инете, ничего на эту тему не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видно плохо искал... Псевдокласс `:visited` позволит стилизовать "посещенную" ссылку. http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-ustanovit-tsvet-poseshchennoy-ssylki

Comment: @ksa, да видимо плохо искал, спасибо))